# is punctuation kept in a bag of words?

Tags: java, regex, nlp, text-processing

I'm creating a bag of words module from the scratch. I'm not sure whether it's best practice in this approach whether to remove punctuation. Consider the sentence

```
I've been "DMX world center" for long time ago.Are u?
```

**Question**: For the bag of words, should I consider

- the token `DMX` (no quotation mark) or `"DMX` (which includes the left quotation mark)
- `u` (without the question mark) or `u?` (with the question mark)

In short, **should I remove all the punctuation marks when getting distinct words?**

Thanks in advance

Updated
This is the code of what I have implemented

Sample text : `ham  , im .. On the snowboarding trip. I was wondering if your planning to get everyone together befor we go..a meet and greet kind of affair? Cheers,`

```
   HashSet<String> bagOfWords = new HashSet<String>();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
   while (reader.ready()) {
       String msg = reader.readLine().split("\t", 2)[1].toLowerCase(); // I get only the 2nd part. 1st part indicate wether message is spam or ham
       String[] words = msg.split("[\\s+\n.\t!?+,]"); // this is the regex that I've used to split words
       for (String word : words) {
           bagOfWords.add(word);
       }
   }
```

Comment: can u post , what you have tried?

Comment: Hi woody, I've added the code snippet in the updated section

Comment: try changing the index as 0 and not 1. in                        String msg = reader.readLine().split("\t", 2)[0]

Comment: Post your output format. It will help us to solve the problem

Comment: I don't have a specific format. I want know what is the best way to consider words. I mean words with double quotes, question marks, exclamations, etc... ("DMX, u? good!) or words without them (DMX, u, good)

Comment: Thanks @Woody. But I just want to know is it the way to break into words? I mean should I get words without punctuation marks or with them?

Comment: yeah that is the way and regarding the punctuation marks, it depends upon the requirement you have.

Comment: It depends a lot on what you want to use the words for after tokenising them. If you can add this information to the question you might get some useful suggestions.

Comment: this is an interesting question without too much info out there! if you're just creating a module, then you should probably leave it up to the module caller to decide whether to keep punctuation or not with an extra argument into it. you may also want to look at [nltk's tokenize() function](http://nltk.org/book/ch03.html) for something somewhat related.

Comment: A common practice in the past has been to split off punctuation into their own entities.  I.e. you would have <I> <'> <ve> <been> <"> <DMX> <World> <Center> <"> <for> <long> <time> <ago> <.> <Are> <u> <?> or maybe identify <DMX World Center> as one entity if you can, and there are various solutions to contractions like <I've>. But this also depends enormously on what you are going to be using this for. For example, for Bayesian classification, you often simply discard the punctuation altogether.

Comment: Thanks you all. All your comments are really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your code

```
 while (reader.ready()) {
       String msg = reader.readLine().split("\t", 2)[1].toLowerCase(); // I get only the 2nd part. 1st part indicate wether message is spam or ham
       String[] words = msg.split("[\\s+\n.\t!?+,]"); // this is the regex that I've used to split words
       for (String word : words) {
           bagOfWords.add(word.replaceAll("[!-+.^:,\"?]"," ").trim()); // it removes all sepecial characters what you mentioned
       }
   }
```

Comment: Actually there is no fault on that section woody. I want get clarify whether should I consider "DMX world center" as "DMX, world, center" or DMX, world, center (without quotes)
And also should I omit punctuation marks such as ?, ! etc... from words and consider words like you?, best! as it is or without them ?
thanks